# Verifying Stokes theorem using line integral

Tags: calculus

> $$F(x, y, z) =(xyz)~\hat{i}+(y)~\hat{j}+(z) \hat{k}$$
>
> S:6x+6y+z=12, first octant

Verify stokes theorem by evaluating both double integral and
Line integral.

My work:
I have calculated the double integral on the x- y plane which came to be zero. But when I evaluate the line integral in x- y plane, it comes to be 9/2.Why are they coming different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint

\begin{align}
\int_C \bf{F} \cdot \bf{dr} &= \int_0^2 y \,dy + \int_2^0 y \,dy+ \int_0^{12}z \,dz+\int_{12}^0 z \,dx \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Other side of Stokes' theorem (Letting $z=12-6x-6y$)
\begin{align}
\bf{\text{curl F}} &= xy {\bf{j}} -xz \bf{k} \\
\int_S \int \bf{\text{curl F}}  \cdot N dS &= \int_S \int \text{curl F}  \cdot (6 {\bf{i}}+6 {\bf{j}}+{\bf{k}}) dA \\
&=\int_0^2 \int_0^{2-x}[6xy-x(12-6x-6y))\,dy \, dx \\
&= \int_0^2 \int_0^{2-x}(12xy-12x+6x^2)\,dy \,dx \\
&= \int_0^2 (6xy^2-12xy+6x^2y)\bigg \rvert_0^{2-x} dx \\
&=0
\end{align}

Further edit
From the line one should be able to see that
\begin{align}
C_1: z=0, dz=0 \\
C_2: y=0, dy=0\\
C_3: x=0, dx=0
\end{align}
Whence
\begin{align}
\int_C \bf{F} \cdot \bf{dr} &= \int_C (xyz dx+ydy + zdz) \\
&= \int_{C_1}y dy+\int_{C_{2}}(ydy + zdz) +\int_{C_{3}}z dz \\
&= \int_0^2 y dy + \int_2^0 y dy+ \int_0^{12}z dz+\int_{12}^0 z\, dz
\end{align}

Comment: But aren't we supposed to find line integral of one boundry curve ie the intersection of the surface with x-y plane

Comment: Yes, that's where the other calculation comes in, I can pose that too but you stating you found it equal to zero means you have the correct answer.

Comment: No I was talking about the line integral. Shouldn't dz be zero here

Comment: But u have included it in line integral in your answer

Comment: See edits Abhinav

Comment: Ah so it's intersection of C1, C2 and C3. Got it

Comment: Yes that's it, cheers

Comment: Why are u not taking projection in yz and xz plane for the double integral...... Shouldn't the answer be sum of them for the curl side of the equation. Please reply

Comment: Or they will come zero similarly

Comment: I set the plane up to $z= \ldots$ and then took a slice in the $\mathrm{xy}$-plane.